# Load Images folder in android gallery

Tags: android, image, image-gallery

I am working on an application, where i take pictures from a camera and store it in a separate folder in sd card. The problem what i am facing is, once the pictures are stored in a folder on sd card the Image folder is not being displayed in android native gallery.
This should be something similar to whatsapp image folder. how is it possible?

Comment: Have you add android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest file

Comment: i am able to store images on sd card but my problem is i want to display those images in android's native gallery

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but maybe you have to tell android, that there are new files. Try searching for MediaStore and MediaScanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the function MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage to create a thumbnail and show the image in the default android gallery.

String imageName = "imagepath";

File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(imageName);

MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
sdImageMainDirectory.getAbsolutePath(),sdImageMainDirectory.getName(), "description");

Answer (score 1):

You need to let the system know that new media has been added before it will show up. Call this after you save the image.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```